# simpleAdapter thumbnail and text and onItemClick handler

Tags: android, classcastexception, onitemclicklistener, simpleadapter

In my  app I need to show a list of thumbnail with their own relative title. 
Here's my implementation.

```
    String tempTarget;
    List<Map<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

   for(int i = 0; i<ARelements.size();i++){
        Element ar = arIterator.next();
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>(2);
        tempTarget = ar.getAttributeValue("TARGET");
        thumbnailBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempTarget), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
        map.put("thumbnail", thumbnailBitmap);
        map.put("titolo", tempTarget);
        data.add(map);
        Log.i("list",thumbnailBitmap.toString());
    }
   arIterator= null;

   SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,data,R.layout.row,new String[] {"thumbnail","titolo"},new int[] {R.id.imageView, R.id.titoloTv});


    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
           @Override  
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, final View componente, int pos, long id){  
               List<Map<String,Object>> res =  new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
               res =  (List<Map<String, Object>>) adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos); //classCastExeption
               Log.i("list","assegamento a res eseguito");
               titoloriga = (String) res.get(pos).get("titolo");
               Log.i("list","assegamento a titoloriga eseguito");
               Log.i("list", "Ho cliccato sull'elemento con titolo" + titoloriga+"    " +Integer.valueOf(pos)+"    "+Long.valueOf(id));
               registerForContextMenu(componente);
               componente.showContextMenu();

           } 

    });
```

I have two problems:
1. The simple adapter show me only the title but not the thumbnail.
2. I don't know how to handle the onItemClick, i need to store the title. In this way I have the ClassCastExeption and the warning of unsafety cast.
Here' s the layout of the single row and of the listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titoloTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/creaButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Crea una nuova realtà aumentata" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Ar già create"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Item click of ListView, you don't need to create a Hash map arraylist again you can get by which is stored in your ArrayList of hashmap.. So change

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
       @Override  
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, final View componente, int pos, long id){  

           String title = data.get(pos).get("titolo");
           String thumbimage = data.get(pos).get("thumbnail");
           registerForContextMenu(componente);
           componente.showContextMenu();

       } 

});
```

Comment: thank's it works. What about the view of the thumbnail?